# How did archers judge distance before range finders?

Tags: military, ancient-history, weapons, combat

Before electronics, was there a method for judging distance in archery?

What methods were used historically?
How were combat archers trained to judge distances?

Comment: I would imagine they learnt through experience and lots of practice. Not a historical source, but this seems interesting: *[Archery Tips: How to Judge Yardage Like a Pro](http://archerydude.com/archery-tips-how-to-judge-yardage-like-a-pro/)*.

Comment: How does a pro quarterback learn to judge the distance for his long passes? Practice, practice, practice from a young age. In both cases being off by just a few feet in range ruins the attempt. The yardages may be shorter for a football pass but the ball speed is also much slower, with passes even more strict on correct range than a faster flying arrow.

Comment: I see, that's interesting - it might be simply that it was done heuristically. I'll wait to see if anyone attempts a full answer.

Comment: These might give some leads on primary source evidence: *[Who Wrote the First “Useful” Archery Manual?](https://muslimheritage.com/first-useful-archery-manual/)* and *[Toxophilus](http://www.armchairhistory.co.uk/pdf/Toxophilus2.pdf)*.

Comment: There are techniques using comparing sizes of known things (e.g. height of a man) with  things like your thumb in a stretched arm, this will give you a reasonable indicator of a distance with practice. There are are modern army manuals on "manual" rangefinding - I mean, the same techniques that work for an ancient archer would also work for a napoleonic or ww1 rifleman or a modern soldier, who also need to estimate ranges in order to target various weaponry.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: I wouldn't say that football passes are more strict, since presumably the receiver is able to move a certain distance to catch the ball.  But the same principle applies anywhere: putting a basketball through a hoop, pitching a baseball or catching a fly ball, even playing frisbee with your dog.

Comment: By.... looking?

Comment: There may be a chance to "pre measure" - walking the expected battle field beforehand, by one or a small detatchment.

Comment: Electronic rangefinding is simply not used in sport archery at all. We either shoot marked distances, where a rangefinder doesn't tell you anything you don't already know or unmarked distance, where estimating range is one of the skills on display, and rangefinders (electronic or otherwise) are banned entirely.
Some jurisdictions permit the use of rangefinders for hunting, others don't.

Comment: @Criggie that idea does make me wonder: would knowing the actual number of paces help at all without specific training based on it? I mean when I try to throw my trash in the bin from 5 metres away, knowing that it's actually 5.3 metres wouldn't really help me

Comment: @llama perhaps; another unstated advantage is to know if the land slopes and whether its up or downhill.  That also affects range.

Comment: The usual method of judging distance was "Hit your target and live. Miss your target and die". This was kind of indirect in terms of *teaching* someone how to estimate range but since those who did well at the first task didn't stand as much of a chance of joining the second group it was a way to limit the pool of archers to those who were good at estimating ranges. Or you could just wait until the screaming hordes were about 20 yards away and then loose a massive volley into their close-packed ranks, turning their fearsome war-cries into screams of dying anguish. Ah, great days - GREAT days!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I'm a horse archer; we use [instinctive archery](https://themodernarcher.com/instinctive-archery-how-to-shoot-the-traditional-way/) – there are no range finders, just a bow, a string an arrow and an archer.  After a few thousand shots at various ranges, your body just knows how to aim – I'm not even conscious of doing it.  Eventually you're able to hit a target from the back of galloping horse reliably (I'm not saying I'm there yet, but I'm working towards it).

It can take me a couple of rounds to sight in when I change distance; the club normally shoots at 10 m, but the range where I go is more convenient at 20 m. When I switch to the longer distance my arrows are low until I correct. I suspect that would vanish if I were to practice more often, but I also suspect that historical archers shot some ranging shots before combat started, and probably used other archers as reference to adjust range.

Not sure I can express this clearly, but when I think about aiming, my aiming declines – it really is instinctual. Trying to control the process leads to error.  Archery is about perfect form – about *this arrow*. One teacher I heard express it as "build a connection between yourself and the target and let the arrow trace that connection."

I overheard one of the instructors mentioning that it was common for historical archers to loose 300 shafts a day; when I'm doing my best I'll loose 144/day 3 days a week. For me this is a hobby/stress relief. For them it was life and death.

The cited reference is only the first one that popped up in my search. You can check for related terms such as traditional archery.  I occasionally practice with some longbow archers from the Society for Creative Anachronism; they don't use range finders either, but they have a slightly different technique for managing range. I'm not a longbow archer, so please take my summary with a grain of salt – I've heard them instructing their students to line up the shot then tilt their bodies above the waist to manage the distance.  (You can't do that atop a horse for reasons of balance, so I've never tried.)  @Pieter Geerkens points out that [Joe Gibbs](https://www.youtube.com/user/Joe8Gibbs) demonstrates this in his videos.

You might want to check out your local chapter of [Horse Archers USA](https://www.horsearchery.us/about/clubs/) or [Mounted Archers of the America](https://www.mountedarchery.org/), the SCA, or other related disciplines. I believe there is also an active traditional bowhunting community – I see their magazines occasionally, and they may have more information.

*Aside: someone attempted an edit and I wanted to clarify.  An archer *looses* a shaft.  Sometimes I lose shafts, but only rarely indoors.  When we lose a shaft outdoors we have to search very hard because we don't want a horse to step on the arrow.  Sometimes people talk about "firing" arrows, but the term "fire" is related to gunpowder. Some people care.  But "loose" is the correct word in this context.*

Comment: Your description of *longbow technique* matches what i have seen [Joe Gibbs](https://www.youtube.com/user/Joe8Gibbs) demonstrate in a few videos. Undoubtedly he discusses it somewhere. it is how we master most hand-eye coordination sports: Judging curling rock speed was my particular forte at one time, but whether it is skipping stones on a pond, playing catch, or pole vaulting judging distances beyond the binocular capability of two eyes is fundamental to mastery.

Comment: Regarding longbow archery, yes, that is how we do it. ;-) It was always a subject of hilarity when traditional archers and "system" archers (those with visors and counterweights attached to their compound bows...) met on the same range. While the "system" archers are able to put much tighter groups on a target at known range, they just couldn't match the traditional archers in putting a good (if not perfect) hit on any target at any (unknown) range. Add gusts of wind to the equation, and the traditionals had a good laugh (humorous, not condescending, we are all archers after all).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I'll admit to a certain amount of that instinctive sniper capability with a soccer ball. Proficient humans can do that kind of thing.

Comment: @DevSolar: Reminds me of top "club curlers" - who can put a rock inside a  2 foot circle on their club's perfect 23 second ice - but are lost competing on a frosty sheet of 20 second ice up north or even the slick 24 second ice across town - never mind the hills and valleys to be found on the occasional rink still on a sand base (instead of concrete) for the ice. Then put them in a hockey arena - Oh my!

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I once had a reigning champion in competitive compound archery ask if he could give my longbow a try... who broke into hysterical laughter when he couldn't pull it more than two or three inches. (As longbows stack -- i.e. get harder to pull -- instead of "going soft" after the initial pull the way compounds do.) He just couldn't pull the thing. He kept embarrassing me on target though... until I suggested we shoot at different targets of differing range, with the slower shooter having to stop when the faster fired his last arrow, and then counting rings... no contest. :-D

Comment: I would say that sighting in at 10m vs 20m  even on a horse is very different from sighting in at 70m vs 90m at a barebow target shoot.

Comment: This is much the same with throwing a deep ball in football.   If your QB is looking at the distance and  calculating... hes never going to get it.   If he want's to practice fades at 30, 40, 50, and 60 yards... he might get good at those drills but again he will never get it.   Your body gets very good at managing wind, angle, velocity, and release speed without thinking about it.   It is part practice and part innate skill.

Comment: I suspect the term you were struggling for when trying to describe why thinking interferes is 'muscle memory'.

Answer (score 43):

#### They mostly didn't care.

In combat, the purpose of an archer was not to land aimed shots on specific targets.  It was to put large amounts of pointy wood-and-steel in the air, in the general direction of a block of enemy troops.  When the block of enemy troops is tens of metres deep and hundreds of metres wide, aiming is largely irrelevant.  For long range shots where an enemy is running over uneven ground, it's basically impossible to predict movement anyway within the arrow's flight time.

In this, archery is more similar to Olympic javelin or hammer throwing.  What matters most is the distance at which you can engage the enemy with your ranged weapons, and the rate of fire you can achieve.  The more shots you can land in the enemy's ranks, the fewer enemy your footmen have to fight.  So long as your arrows are landing *somewhere* within the enemy ranks, you're good.  Bonus points if (as at [the Battle of Crecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Cr%C3%A9cy)) you outrange your opponents' archers enough that you can shoot them with virtual impunity.

Comment: You still need to roughly estimate the distance to not shoot too short or too long.

Comment: Roughly, sure, but nothing like the kind of accuracy for any modern target shooting.

Comment: A bad distance estimate can easily put you several meters off target short or long, with modern archery gear.
This is especially true as you approach the limits of your range.

Comment: What you're overlooking here is that many of the archers probably hunted for food when they were not in an army (or even when they were - see foraging).  You don't get to shoot a deer, rabbits, or other critters at nicely marked ranges, nor can you really expect them to hold still while you measure the distance.

Comment: Javelin throwing is throwing as far as possible. Battle archery (like the modern discipline of **Clout Archery**, btw) is (oversimplifying) hitting an m×n area in distance d. Enemy formations to be hit could be anywhere between 25 m and almost 400 m. You don't want to spread a hundred arrows over the hemisphere and over hundreds of meters. This is pure waste. Your post lets it seem as there is no aiming involved, nor necessary. But given the range of hundreds of meters, this is worse than shooting shotguns at a duck 200 m away. In battle, you really want to concentrate shots.

Comment: @Leliel And the point of my answer was that since the target is tens or hundreds of metres in each direction, you don't need to be that accurate. Several yards beyond that area, sure, you've missed. But you didn't need to be more accurate than "hit a football pitch".

Comment: @jamesqf I'm not saying they couldn't (or at least that some of them couldn't). But they certainly didn't need to. And more than that, a full-size longbow is a pretty lousy tool for hunting small targets in woods - you want something a bit smaller, and you certainly aren't hitting those distances. So most recruits did need training on the longbow, to get them used to the longer ranges they'd need to be firing over, training for strength and not accuracy

Comment: @Graham: Have you actually tried longbows? I don't see why it should be impracticable in typical european forests. And, the Welsh and English DID use it for hunting (according to Wikipedia and Bernard Cornwell's well researched literature).

Comment: @Graham: First, at least as I read the question, the OP is asking about archers in general, not exclusively combat archers.  There is (at least from my limited experience) a lot of commonality between different types of traditional bows, just as there is a lot in common with hunting squirrels with a .22, and open-field combat with an M-14.

Comment: @phresnel My point is that you don't need the range a longbow gives you for shooting small game at short distances, and the long, deep pull is a disadvantage.  It's good for larger game like deer, of course, with a projectile which carries much more kinetic energy.

Comment: @jamesqf For small game at relatively close distances, of course you're looking more at instinct, and somewhat for targets too.  And for targets you can pace out the distance.  But for massed volleys at long range, any kind of aiming is basically unnecessary.  Aiming for a target, "a miss is as good as a mile".  But pointing generally in the direction of a whole bunch of approaching infantry, it really doesn't matter which one of them your arrow hits. :)

Comment: @WillCrawford Ah! Rereading that comment I see now what you mean. Not necessarily "ditch the bow and use something else" but rather "get a shorter bow." That makes more sense. I'll still disagree, but at this point it's a matter of preference. Removing all my previous comments as they are obsolete now...

Comment: @Loduwijk Will got there first. :) Yes, that was basically my point - a 6 foot longbow in a confined space is not ideal, but a shortbow is more manageable. Of course it depends on where you are though.

Answer (score 5):

Ranging wouldn't have been as important as it is today. The importance of ranging comes from the "first shot" advantage - being able to drop your projectiles onto your chosen target first time accurately (whether that is from a sniper rifle or an artillery piece) is important in modern warfare because most conflicts are decided by who gets the first hit in successfully. Add to this that modern weapons are also exponentially more expensive than those of ages past (a single "smart" missile often comes in at several thousand pounds these days), and thus such smart weapons need to be able to hit first time, every time which is where the reliance on ranging and other ballistic factors come into play.

Medieval weaponry doesn't have the accuracy of modern weaponry. Long bows and the like relied less on individual accuracy of the bowmen and more on massed concentration of fire on the target area. Medieval armies were also large compared to modern engagements and thus the element of surprise was lessened, if not non-existant.

During sieges, for example, you had the time to estimate ranges using given landmarks - siege weapons were often built where they were to be employed and thus there was plenty of time to send scouts to get ranges. Not to mention such sieges often lasted weeks and thus the first few shots from any siege weapon would have been ranging shots at best - the defenders were unlikely to be able to move either.

Answer (score 4):

With just a little practice, most people can learn to judge distance fairly accurately. Even in modern times, use of a rangefinder is situational. In hunting with a modern sight, it is important to know the range of a shot. Yet it can also be inconvenient to break out and use an electronic rangefinder.

3D shoots are a type of archery contest intended to simulate actual hunting conditions. Typically, rangefinders are not allowed. What I have seen many people do in practicing for 3D shoots, is to judge distance without a rangefinder and shoot. Then use an electronic rangefinder after the shot to check on their accuracy. With only a few weeks of practice doing this, a person can usually become accurate at estimating distance to within a few yards. That is as accurate as needed for archery.

As others have mentioned, knowing exact distance may have been less important in the past. However, I've talked to people on construction sites and in other cases where they were able to accurately describe distance prior to measuring. This was not an uncommon skill for people to have prior to rangefinders and modern measurement, if those people were in a trade that required it.

To the extent that understanding range was important to historical archers, I am confident that many of them would have had the same kind of sense of distance that these construction workers and 3d shoot participants demonstrate.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately you can use recent history to answer your question.  Until very recently, Bradley fighting vehicles (and others) did not have a range finders.  Range were based upon the estimation of the commander and gunner.  Modern day snipers are trained to judge range without the use of electronics.

I'd dispute that range estimation was not important in antiquity ballistics.   Ammunition cost time, labor, and probably money.   Even finding appropriate sized rocks for catapults (and their ilk) would be labor intensive and dangerous.  Firing the various instruments caused wear.  How would a commander react if some of his missile weapons broke with no meaningful effect on the enemy?  This could be somewhat mitigated by test shots, say one archer files an arrow and the rest of the archer uses that to judge the range.

The best way to judge range is to construct a range card.  Walk the battlefield measure the ranges, note any depressions that could offer the enemy cover.  In the movie **Kingdom of Heaven** this is what they are doing for the defense of Jerusalem, marking ranges with painted rocks.  The limited catapult shots had to count.  Range cards are typically limited to deliberate defenses, but ranges could also be stepped out if employing spies when on the attack.  In the movie **The Green Berets** a person dressed as a allied soldier is caught measuring (by pace count) to a VC desired target.

Failing that, one method that worked for me, was dividing the distance.  It is easy to calculate the distance of a football field, and then estimate the number of those a target is away from you.  So about 10 football fields would be about 1000 yards or meters.  With archers, we are talking much shorter distances so it was easier to be more precise.

There are a whole series of you tube videos on range estimation and many of the techniques would be available to gunners from antiquity.  Videos on using the reticle method, would not be applicable.  Note that light and the color of the targets have an impact on range estimation and leads to the skill of the "gunner".

Answer (score 2):

**How did archers judge distance before range finders?**

As the old saying goes: **practice makes perfect**.

When I was younger, I used to hunt deer and black bear with bow and arrows. Bear hunting with bow and arrows is now illegal. We used to draw a life size deer and pin it on hay bails for target practice sometime just before open hunting season. By practicing at various distances, we easily became accustomed to estimating the distance between ourselves and our targets. This is a method, I am sure that combat archers would have used to estimate the distance between themselves and the enemy.

[Three ways to judge distances on unmarked field rounds](https://www.bow-international.com/features/three-ways-to-judge-distances-on-unmarked-field-rounds/)

Some of the archers could shot arrows at a 45 degree angle in order to tell the maximum distance. This way, both gravity and wind would be known to the archers in any given battle situation.

> At maximum range the archers all shot at an angle of 45 degrees for longest distance. As the distance reduced, the men in the front ranks lowered their elevation and those in the rear ranks raised their, so that the charging knights were subjected both to arrows falling from above as well as being shot directly at them. - [With a Bended Bow: Archery in Medieval and Renaissance Europe](https://books.google.ca/books?id=sveaDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT245&lpg=PT245&dq=arrows%20shot%20at%2045%20degrees%20are%20the%20longest&source=bl&ots=0UWBUJ5hR7&sig=ACfU3U1zlvt2lPKTior-m1uoCn06C1ygNA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA0O2034bxAhUVup4KHcsBCJsQ6AEwF3oECBAQAg#v=onepage&q=arrows%20shot%20at%2045%20degrees%20are%20the%20longest&f=false)